# Powershell Replace two empty lines with one

Tags: powershell, replace

I have text files that are generated with 2 empty lines between each block of text. I could use Notepad++ to do this using replace \r\n\r\n with \r\n, but there has to be a way to do this automatically.

I've tried to come up with something in Powershell, but nothing has worked so far.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
(Get-Content .\test.txt).Replace("\n\n",'\n') | Set-Content .\test.txt
(Get-Content .\test.txt).Replace("\s+\r\n+",'\r\n') | Set-Content .\test.txt
(Get-Content .\test.txt).Replace("\r\n+",'') | Set-Content .\test.txt
(Get-Content .\test.txt).Replace("\n+",'') | Set-Content .\test.txt
(Get-Content .\test.txt).Replace("\r\n\r\n",'\r\n') | Set-Content .\test.txt
(Get-Content .\test.txt).Replace("^(\s+\r\n)",'\r\n') | Set-Content .\test.txt
(Get-Content .\test.txt).Replace("^(\s+\r\n+)",'\r\n') | Set-Content .\test.txt
(Get-Content .\test.txt).Replace("^(\r\n+)",'\r\n') | Set-Content .\test.txt
(Get-Content .\test.txt).Replace("\r\n",'\b') | Set-Content .\test.txt
```

Comment: What are the contents of `Test.txt`  You might be able to remove the white spaces using the `Trim()` method.

Comment: Use ` instead of \ to escape control characters

Comment: @Ramil If you found any of the answers helpful, please accept them.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the contents.. I'm currently working on a test file, that looks something like that.
text <empty line1><empty line2>next block of text (sorry, I don't know how to add empty lines in comments, but you should get what I mean :P)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Get-Content` returns a list of strings, and not a whole piece of text, like you need. Ovbiously you meant running this `Replace` method on a string, and not on a list of strings.

Use `Get-Content -Raw .\test.txt` to load the file content as one long string.

Also, the correct form of the replacement would be:

```
Replace("`r`n`r`n", "`r`n")
```

To sum up:

```
(Get-Content -Raw .\test.txt).Replace("`r`n`r`n", "`r`n") | Set-Content .\test.txt
```

Will do the job.

**Another approach** would be to just filter out empty lines:

```
$data = Get-Content .\test.txt
$data | Where-Object { $_ } | Set-Content .\test.txt
```

Comment: *Another approach would be to just filter out empty lines:* - `$data -ne ''`

Comment: @iTayb Thanks, it works :D

I used the first solution since I don't want to remove all empty lines.

So Powershell sometimes accepts regex.. commands as such \n, but sometimes requires the backtick version `n. Can you point me to some material why is that ?

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell uses backticks `` ` `` not backslashes `\` to escape special characters:

```
(Get-Content .\test.txt) -replace "(`r?`n){2}",$([Environment]::Newline) | Set-Content .\test.txt
```

Using the regex `-replace` operator with a conditional carriage return will match any type of newline.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I found it out yesterday when I tried to escape _ (underscore) between a variable and a string (like: Rename-Item -Path $LogPath -NewName "$Today`_logfile.log"). Useful for anyone who haven't figured this out yet :)